# How to Count rows of two joined tables using sequelizejs

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two tables **user** and **like**. The relationship is many to one, a user can have many likes. I want to count how many likes a user has and return an object with the user's name and a column count with the number of likes, however, I find it difficult to do it in sequelize.

Below is a working raw query and the result is a table.

## |username |count |

## |John Doe |  2   |

```
SELECT us.username, COUNT(lk.other_user_id)
FROM user as us
INNER JOIN like as lk
ON us.id = lk.other_user_id
WHERE us.id = 40
GROUP BY us.username
```

Here is the sequelize code I have tried.

```
like.findAll({
        attributes: {
          include: [[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('other_user_id')), 'like_count']],
        },
        where: { other_user_id: 40 },
        include: [{
          model: user,
          attributes: [],
          where: { id: 40 },
        }],

        group: ['user.username'],
      });
```

The result should be an object with the user's **name** and a property **count** with the number of likes. Instead is returning all rows and count as 1 for each object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was including the **user** but in my SQL raw query in question above on **join** condition I tested **user.id = like.other_user_id** but the foreign key on the **like** table is **user_id** and points to **id** column on the **user** table, therefore, sequelize couldn't find any row that has **user.id = like.other_user_id**, instead it was matching as **user.id = like.user_id**.

Below is my solution where I joined the tables on **custom columns**.

```
const { ok, result, error } = await handlePromise(like.findAll({
        attributes: [[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('like.other_user_id')), 'like_count']],
        include: [
          {
            model: user,
            where: { id: userId },
            attributes: ['username'],
            on: {
              col1: sequelize.where(sequelize.col('user.id'), '=', sequelize.col('like.other_user_id')),
            },
          },
        ],
        group: ['user.username'],
        raw: true,
      }));
```